# How to format a number from other locale to normal en locale

Tags: java, formatting

I have a String `"45,78"`. How can i format it to normal format like `45.78` in java?

Probably i think i need to create some format object and than format this according to en number format.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the predefined [DecimalFormats](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) that the JDK offers for Locales:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String input = "45,78";
    NumberFormat from = DecimalFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
    NumberFormat to = DecimalFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);
    String output = to.format(from.parse(input));
    System.out.println(output); // "45.78"
}
```

Chose Locales to suit you.

This is another case of "don't reinvent the wheel" and "use what the JDK offers"